# Webpage's Scroll should be visible When Overlay is Active

Tags: javascript, html, css, overlay

Goal:
When you open the overlay, the webpage's scroll (not overlay's scroll) should be visible but not active to use.

Problem:
It is irritated to see that the page moves to the right side when you invisible the scroll and when you visible the scroll the page moves to the right side in relation to overlay.

Is there a way to do it?

Thanks!

```js
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "100%";
    
     $('body').addClass('noscroll');   
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "0%";
    
     $('body').removeClass('noscroll');
    
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.overlay {
    height: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.8);
    overflow-y: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay-content {
   position: relative;
   top: 10%;
   width: 70%;
   text-align: left;
   margin: 30px auto;
   background: white;
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 100%;  
    
}

.overlay a {
    padding: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover, .overlay a:focus {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.overlay .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 45px;
    font-size: 60px;
}


.noscroll { 
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myNav" class="overlay">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <div class="overlay-content">
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
    
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>        
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">CANDY</a>    
  </div>
</div>

<h2>Fullscreen Overlay Nav Example</h2>
<p>Click on the element below to open the fullscreen overlay navigation menu.</p>
<p>In this example, the navigation menu will slide downwards from the top:</p>
  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>    
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>    
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>    
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>    
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>    
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>    
  <br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>    
  <br/>  
<br/>    
  <br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>    
  <br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>    
  <br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>    
  <br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>    
   
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>  

<br/>    
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>    
  <br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>    
  <br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>    
  <br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add "position: fixed; overflow-y:scroll" to your no scroll class.

if you don't want it to go to the top, get the current X position based on the body's current scroll and set the Y offset to that

```js
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "100%";
    $(document).scrollTop()
     $('body').addClass('noscroll');   

}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "0%";
    
     $('body').removeClass('noscroll');
$('body').scroll(function() { alert("scroll") });
    
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    overflow-y: scroll;

}

.overlay {
    height: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.8);
    overflow-y: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay-content {
   position: relative;
   top: 10%;
   width: 70%;
   text-align: left;
   margin: 30px auto;
   background: white;
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 100%;  
    
}

.overlay a {
    padding: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover, .overlay a:focus {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.overlay .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 45px;
    font-size: 60px;
}


.noscroll { 
  position: fixed; overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myNav" class="overlay">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <div class="overlay-content">
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
    
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>        
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">CANDY</a>    
  </div>
</div>

<h2>Fullscreen Overlay Nav Example</h2>
<p>Click on the element below to open the fullscreen overlay navigation menu.</p>
<p>In this example, the navigation menu will slide downwards from the top:</p>
  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>    
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>    
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>    
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>    
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>    
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>    
  <br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>    
  <br/>  
<br/>    
  <br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>    
  <br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>    
  <br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>    
  <br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>    
   
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>  

<br/>    
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>    
  <br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>    
  <br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>    
  <br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>  
<br/>
```

Comment: wait, i see what you mean, checking into this

Comment: How does it go?

Comment: How does it go?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (scroll will go to top when is clicked but will be disabled):

```
function noscroll() {
  window.scrollTo( 0, 0);
}

function openNav() {
   document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "100%";
   window.addEventListener('scroll', noscroll);  
}

function closeNav() {
   document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "0%";
  window.removeEventListener('scroll', noscroll)
}
```

Comment: It is almost complete. When I click on the overlay button and the webpage's scroll is visible but you still can use it.

Comment: How does it go?